# How to manage aggregations SSAS Cube?

Tags: sql, ssas, olap-cube

I have OLAP Cube with two dimensions.

For example Product and ProductType

And I have a measure with Aggregation Function = "sum"

How to implement Aggregation function which deepens on ProductType value.

For some ProductType it is "sum" for some is "average"?

Comment: Kindly share sample data, query you tired and desired result.

Comment: I am fairly new to OLAP just have to change existing cube for reports.Looks like I need to implement calculated measure?

Comment: No problem, but to help you we need sample data along with desired output

Comment: [Product].[ProductName], [Product].[ProductTypeId], [ProductType] .[TypeName], Measure.[ProductValue]   IF [ProductType] = 1 agregationFunction = "sum" else agregationFunction = "average"